# Pass HTML5-Validation-Event in hidden Tab to JavaScript-Function

Tags: javascript, html, validation

**The Setup**

- HTML-page with **2 tabs** (build with Bootstrap Tabbable nav)
- both of the 2 tabs are surrounded by exactly **one form-tag**
- there is **one submit button**, which is constantly shown, independent of which tab is currently active
- only **tab 1 contains form fields** (the form fields have HTML5 "required"-attributes)

**The Situation**

- the user has **tab number 2 active**...
- ...and fires "submit"
- let's assume, there is a **HTML5 validation error on tab 1**

**The Problem**

- the **HTML5-validation is not shown** (because the user has tab 2 active and the error is shown on tab 1)
- the user would manually have to switch to tab 1 to see the error

**The Question**

- how can I manage to **automatically switch to tab number 1** in this situation?
- is there an easy solution? (maybe passing the HTML5-Validation-Event to JavaScript somehow?)

I would be very happy if somebody could help me out here. Creative ideas are very welcome. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946714/event-listener-valid-for-html5-forms?rq=1 There's an `invalid` event which is thrown by the `form` element. As far as the other questions go, I'd need to see more code to give an answer.

Comment: @Mike: Thank you for your comment! I have solved the problem with a new thinking approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about the whole problem, and came up with this:

- If there will be validation errors thrown, then they have to be on tab 1. In other words: validation errors can only arise in tab 1.
- So I decided to write my own submit-function!

How I solved it (more detailed):

1.) "Degraded" the submit-button to a "plain old" button

2.) Added a onclick-event on that button, that fires the "submitTabs()"-Function

3.) Custom function

```
function submitTabs()
{
    // always get tab 1 to front
    $('a[href=#tab_with_fields]').tab('show');

    // submit form manually
    $('form:first').submit();
}
```

Now, whenever I submit the form, tab 1 gets active and will be shown. When there are HTML5-Validation errors, they will be displayed. If there are no errors, the tab gets active for a second or two, the form is being submitted and redirects to a different page.