# Check validity of as required marked fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I do not want to perform a submit action when pressing the "submit" button on my form but rather perform some data manipulation and then submit the form using javascript `form.submit` - as such I do not use the `<input type="submit">` element in my form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="entry" id="entry" required />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="manipulate_and_submit(this.form, this.form.entry);" />
</form>
```

With the script being something like:

```
function manipulate_and_submit(form, entry) {
    var val = entry.value;
    var hidden = document.createElement("input");
    form.appendChild(hidden);
    hidden.type = "hidden";
    hidden.name = "m";
    hidden.value = generate_other_value(val);
    entry.value = "";
    form.submit();
}
```

But before submitting I want to validate the entry and other elements of the form - I can do that manually ofc. but HTML5 gives us the required and so many other attributes - how can I simply integrate them? Is there something like `form.isValid()` ? Googling "validate javascript html form" just gives me examples that deal with the manual validation in javascript from "ye olde times" ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `checkValidity`, which is a method provided by `HTMLFormElement`. In your example, it would be something like `if ( !form.checkValidity() ) { code here }`. From MDN:

> [checkValidity] Returns true if all controls that are subject to constraint validation satisfy their constraints, or false if some controls do not satisfy their constraints. Fires an event named invalid at any control that does not satisfy its constraints; such controls are considered invalid if the event is not canceled.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/HTMLFormElement)

As that says, it also fires an `invalid` event at every invalid form item. Then you can just make your own handler to show invalidity, like something described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948050/2280630).

Comment: While that helps it does not cause the form to show it's validation error messages - is there a way to trigger these?