# Is there an event listener for when html5 form gets validated before submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have looked over but no clue if there is a way to know if form was validated.

Exemple:

- User click the submit button
- Form is invalid, so submit event is not triggered
- This is where I need to `.addClass('form-feedback')` to `#my-form`...

The only way I found is to put:

```
$('#my-submit-btn').click( () => $('#my-form').addClass('form-feedback'))
```

Is there a simpler and more universal way to do that in javascript?

**Edit:** looked at [Event Listener valid for HTML5 forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946714/event-listener-valid-for-html5-forms) and all answers mentionned a CSS solution and do not mention an event listener...**But** The OP give me the answer in his question (see below)

Thanks ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event Listener valid for HTML5 forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946714/event-listener-valid-for-html5-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid) event is sent to any invalid fields in the form when submitting. I don't think there's one for the form as a whole, but you can use `invalid` to set the invalid state and `submit` (and/or `input` on the fields) to set the valid state.

Exemple: https://codepen.io/geekschool/pen/wjqvMV?editors=1010#0